# Help with Propositional Logic Proof

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

I am having difficulty understanding this propositional logic problem that I came across in my textbook.

Prove   $\neg Q$.

1. $\neg( Q $\rightarrow$ P )$ **Given**
2. $\neg P$ **Given**
3. $\neg P \rightarrow \neg Q \rightarrow ( Q \rightarrow P )$ **FL3**
4. $\neg P \rightarrow \neg Q$ **1,3 MT**
5. $\neg Q$ **2,4 MP**

Shouldn't line 4 be $\neg(\neg P \rightarrow \neg Q)$ because of Modus Tollens?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: ¬Q does NOT follow from ¬(Q → P) and ¬P. [Something has got mis-copied -- which textbook?]

Comment: It's called A First Course in Mathematical Logic and Set Theory. Its written by Michael L. O’Leary. The example is 1.2.16 on Section 1.2. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The inference rules (page 25) are stated for *propositional forms*: $p,q,r$. Thus, 1. $¬(Q→P)$ has the "form" $¬q$ and 3. $(¬P→¬Q) → (Q→P)$ has the form $p → q$. See **MT**.

Comment: (¬P→¬Q)→(Q→P) has the form p→q,and we are given  ¬(Q→P) which has the form ¬q. So according to MT, we should get ¬p which would be ¬(¬P→¬Q). Am I incorrect?

Comment: You are right; as per first comment above, the proof of the textbook is incorrect.

Comment: You can check with truth table: with $Q$ TRUE abd $P$ FALSE we have $\lnot (Q \to P)$ TRUE, and thus the premises are both TRUE and the conclusion is FALSE.

Comment: Double check that you got your Ps and Qs straight.  $\lnot P$ follows from $\lnot (Q \to P)$ so it is unlikely they are both givens.